# problem with SQLite for .NET 4.0

Tags: sqlite

I have downloaded latest version of SQLite. It works great with .Net 4.0. But it is consisted from 3 assemblies not on assembly. It has an extra `SQLite.Interop.dll` that can not be referenced in Visual Studio 2010. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Personally I reverted to 1.0.66 because of this issue.

In my development environment, I was able to make it work not by adding SQLite.Interop.dll as a reference of my project, but rather by having it copied next to System.Data.Sqlite.dll in my bin directory. When I tried to deploy my application by doing the same thing on some Win XP machine, it failed miserably. That's why I reverted the to the over a year old 1.0.66.

I'm hoping the this will be fixed soon and that whatever is in SQLite.Interop.dll will be unified in System.Data.Sqlite.dll.

The issue is documented in http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/tktview?name=54e52d4c6f

**EDIT (2011-07-03):**
Seems like the ticket is fixed and you can now [download](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) the all-in-one dll again.